# How to check keys and values in nested Associations?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, associations, infinite-loop

Considering we have a an association:

```
assc = <|"A" -> <|"a" -> 1, "aa" -> 2|>, "B" -> 0, "C" -> 5,"D" -> <|"d" -> 2, "dd" -> 12|>|>
```

Let's also consider we have 2 known lists and one list for nested keys 
(**
 - *how to create this list?*
**):

```
bigKeys = {"A", "D"}
lst1 = {"a", "dd", "B"}
lst2 = {"aa", "d", "C"}
```

I would like to loop over `assc` and assign the values for the keys that are from `lst1` and are **not** `bigKeys` - **0**, and to the values for the keys that are from `lst2` and again are **not** `bigKeys` - **1**.

As a result to have:

```
asscNew = <|"A" -> <|"a" -> 0, "aa" -> 1|>, "B" -> 0, "C" -> 1,  "D" -> <|"d" -> 1, "dd" -> 0|>|>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? I think it is an intruiging question with an excellent answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution will traverse all nested associations regardless of depth and replace each value with the value that corresponds to its key in `replacements`.

```
f[Rule[key_, assoc_Association]] := Rule[key, AssociationMap[f, assoc]]
f[Rule[key_, val_]] := Rule[key, key /. replacements]

replacements = {
   "a" -> 1, "dd" -> 1, "B" -> 1,
   "aa" -> 0, "d" -> 0, "C" -> 0
   };

assoc = <|"A" -> <|"a" -> 1, "aa" -> 2|>, "B" -> 0, "C" -> 5, 
 "D" -> <|"d" -> 2, "dd" -> 12|>|>;

AssociationMap[f, assoc]
(* Out: <|"A" -> <|"a" -> 1, "aa" -> 0|>, "B" -> 1, "C" -> 0, 
 "D" -> <|"d" -> 0, "dd" -> 1|>|> *)
```

`key /. replacements` can be replaced by a more general transformation `func[key, val]`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Pickett, but this not really what I want to. I don't want to have static list to replace. I want to work dynamically on values. For example let's say, for the keys that are in lst1 check if the value is DateObject.

Comment: @SuTron Can't you modify my solution to do this? Just replace `key /. replacements` with `yourDynamicFunction[key, val]`.

Answer (score 3):

`MapIndexed` can be used to map a function to the inner-most values in nested associations, for example:

```
MapIndexed[f, <| "A" -> <|"a" -> 1|>|>, {-1}]

(* <|"A" -> <|"a" -> f[1, {Key["A"], Key["a"]}]|>|> *)
```

The level specification `{-1}` selects only the deepest level in the expression.  Note how `f` receives not only the value (`1`), but also the keys used to locate that particular value (`{Key["A"], Key["a"]}`).

Knowing this, we can define a helper function `val` which applies the rules specified in the question:

```
val[_, {___, Key[k_]}] /; MemberQ[lst1, k] := 0
val[_, {___, Key[k_]}] /; MemberQ[lst2, k] := 1
val[v_, _] := v
```

Now, `MapIndexed` can provide the desired result:

```
MapIndexed[val, assc, {-1}]

(* <|"A"-> <|"a"->0, "aa"->1|>, "B"-> 0, "C"-> 1, "D"-> <|"d"->1, "dd"->0|>|> *)

% === asscNew

(* True *)
```

Note that this solution automatically ignores keys that have nested associations -- there is no need to use `bigKeys`.  If it is important to take `bigKeys` into consideration for some other reason, then we need only add one more rule (which must be the *first* rule):

```
ClearAll[val]
(* new rule *)
val[v_, {Key[k_], ___}] /; MemberQ[bigKeys, k] := v
(* same rules as before *)
val[_, {___, Key[k_]}] /; MemberQ[lst1, k] := 0
val[_, {___, Key[k_]}] /; MemberQ[lst2, k] := 1
val[v_, _] := v
```

This technique generalizes nicely to complex nested structures, allowing each value to be transformed by an arbitrary function of that value and its location ("path") within the structure.  It also works with nested mixtures of lists and associations.  By relaxing the level specification in `MapIndexed`, any or all levels of a structure can be transformed.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a simple approach using the function `Part` (its shorthand is `[[ ]]`):

### 1.

If you write your list `lst1` rather that way:

```
newlst1 = {{"A", "a"}, {"D", "dd"}, {"B"}}
```

you can assign any value (for example here `999`) to all these keys simply with:

```
(assc[[##]] = 999) & @@@ newlst1;
```

You can check the result:

```
assc
```

> `<|"A" -> <|"a" -> 999, "aa" -> 2|>, "B" -> 999, "C" -> 5, 
>    "D" -> <|"d" -> 2, "dd" -> 999|>|>`

### 2.

Allright, let's say you don't want to modify your `lst1={"a", "dd", "B"};`, 
the keys are **unique** so you don't want to loose your time.

Then, we'll just need to generate this key map first in order to help us:

```
keymap = Reap@MapIndexed[Sow[Rest@{##}] &, assc, {0, Infinity}] // 
    Flatten[#, 3] & // DeleteCases[#, {}] & // Map[#[[-1, 1]] -> # &, #] &
```

> `{"a" -> {Key["A"], Key["a"]}, "aa" -> {Key["A"], Key["aa"]}, 
>    "A" -> {Key["A"]}, "B" -> {Key["B"]}, "C" -> {Key["C"]}, 
>    "d" -> {Key["D"], Key["d"]}, "dd" -> {Key["D"], Key["dd"]}, 
>    "D" -> {Key["D"]}}`

Then for example to assign a value, you just do (almost as in 1./):

```
(assc[[##]] = 111111) & @@@ (lst1 /. keymap);
```

You can check:

```
assc
```

> `<|"A" -> <|"a" -> 111111, "aa" -> 2|>, "B" -> 111111, "C" -> 5, 
>    "D" -> <|"d" -> 2, "dd" -> 111111|>|>`

### Explanation

You can use `Part` or `[[ ]]` with Associations almost as you do with `List`s, except you use Keys as parameters (see the [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) doc.).

Let's try some examples:

Given

```
assc = <|"A" -> <|"a" -> 1, "aa" -> 2|>, "B" -> 0, "C" -> 5, 
  "D" -> <|"d" -> 2, "dd" -> 12|>|>
```

see what does:

```
assc[["A"]]
```

> `<|"a" -> 1, "aa" -> 2|>`

```
assc[["A", "a"]]
```

> `1`

and you can directly assign new values:

```
assc[["A", "a"]] = 123456789;
assc
```

> <|"A" -> <|"a" -> 123456789, "aa" -> 2|>, "B" -> 0, "C" -> 5, "D" ->
>   <|"d" -> 2, "dd" -> 12|>|>